# Saxon/Javax Transform from multiple XML Files/Strings

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

This code is in Java and uses Saxon

I am implementing a transform function to transform xml and several secondary xml sources
All of the inputs are not files, so I cannot use document() or other methods that define files directly

```
String transform(String xml, List<String> secondaryXmls, String xslt);
```

It outputs the transformed xml result

I am successful in applying the transformation from xslt to the single xml file, but I have difficulties in applying transformation that also utilize the secondaryXmls. I have done my research and still could not find the right method to apply these

here is a snapshot of the code

```
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);

    Document transformerDoc = loadXMLFromString(xslt);
    Source transformerSource = new DOMSource(transformerDoc);
    Transformer transformer =  tFactory.newTransformer(transformerSource); 

    Document sourceDoc = loadXMLFromString(xml);        
    Source source = new DOMSource(sourceDoc);

    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    Document resultDoc = (Document) result.getNode();

    return getStringFrom(resultDoc);
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Which is the better way:

1. concatenating all the xmls, transform, return only the original part filtering the concatenated secondary xmls
2. Write a code that adds

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="asd" select="document('asd')">
   ```

   on top of the xslt string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - get rid of all that DOM stuff! Using the DOM with Saxon slows it down by a factor of ten. Let Saxon build the trees in its own format, by using a StreamSource or SAXSource, and a StreamResult. Or you can build a tree in Saxon format yourself, if you want, using the s9api DocumentBuilder class.

Then as to the answer to your question: here are three possible solutions:

(a) supply the documents as a stylesheet parameter of type document-node()* (that is, a sequence of document nodes). In the Java, convert your list of XML strings to a list of document nodes by calling Configuration.buildDocument() on each one.

(b) write a URIResolver whose effect is to interpret the URI doc/3 as meaning the third document in the list; then use document('doc/3') to fetch that document.

(c) write a CollectionURIResolver which makes the whole collection of documents available using the collection() function.

Comment: Thanks! I use solution c by implementing my own URI. It works perfectly

Comment: Based on other stackoverflow questions, DOM is preferable to Stream/SAX if we want to change the XML structure (which I believe is closely related to transforming it). Should I still use Stream/SAX in replacement for DOM?

Comment: If you're using Saxon, the only possible reason for supplying a DOM is that the data is constructed by an application that uses DOM and you don't want to change it. Allowing Saxon to build its own tree from a StreamSource or SAXSource will make the transformation go about 10 times faster than if you supply a DOM.